# Opencart: List Products from a Specific Category on Homepage

Tags: list, opencart, product, categories

I am trying to figure out a way to generate a list of products from a specific category on the home page. I want to use something similar to the Featured Module or the Latest Module but be able to pick the products to be shown by their category. I am currently using the Featured Module but I have to manually enter each Product into the module.

Is there an extension or a way to modify an existing module so that I can select a category and have the products display in a similar way.

Thanks in advance for any ideas or help.

Matt

Answer (score 0):

Go and install modules that can display products by categories. You can download them from the opencart website